# Take a string as the parameter of a function then print every possible slice of that string. Precede each slice with index numbers

Tags: python, string, loops, iteration, slice

Take a string(input outside of the function) as the only parameter of a function, then print every possible slice of that string (including the entire string).  Precede each slice with the indices of the slice

I've tried multiple things, I'll post my code below..I can't seem to figure this out.

```
userInput = input("Please...enter a string...")

def stringSlicer(userInput):

    index1 = 0
    index2 = 0
    while index1 <= len(userInput)-1:
        print(index2, index1, userInput[:index1+1])
        index1 += 1


stringSlicer(userInput)
```

So far, this will take a string as an input and display each slice in order starting at index 0..
i.e. If I pass `"two"` as the input, it'll return

```
0 t
1 tw
2 two
```

What I'm supposed to have:

```
0 0 t
0 1 tw
0 2 two
1 0 w
1 1 wo
2 0 o
```

I suspect that I can make the function start at a specific index and use a loop to traverse the string and return each index value relevant to the first, I'm just unsure on how to go about doing that.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using double list comprehension like below

```py
st = "two"
result = [f"{inner_i}{outer_i}%s"%(st[inner_i: outer_i+1]) 
     for inner_i in range(len(st)) 
     for outer_i in range(len(st)) if inner_i<=outer_i]

print(result)
```

Comment: no need of ```from itertools import combinations```,  removed it

Answer (score 0):

To print all possible slices you need nested loop. The outer loop will indicate starting index and inner loop will indicate ending index. Pseudo code is as follows.

```
for start_index in range(len(user_input)):
    for end_index in range(start_index+1, len(user_input)+1):
        print(start_index, end_index-start_index-1, user_input[start_index:end_index])
```

Comment: This does not produce the output OP needs

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(userInput)): 
    for j in range(i+1, len(userInput)+1): 
        print(i, j-i-1, userInput[i:j])
```

Answer (score -2):

You should try something along the lines:

```
length = len(user_input)
for i in range( length-1 ) :
    for j in range( i, length ) :
        print i, j, user_input[i:j+1]
```

Comment: This does not produce the output OP needs